# 'ID No. issued to you by your government' field for Japanese Visa form

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, japan, paperwork

I am an Indian student and am going to Japan for my summer internship this May. There is a field `ID No. issued to you by your government` which I am supposed to fill in the Visa application form. What should I fill here since `Aadhar` is still not authenticated by the Government of India as an identity number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Japanese consulate in New Zealand](http://www.auckland.nz.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/visa_faq.html):

> **The visa application form asks for my "I.D. No. issued to you by your
> government". What is this?**
>
> The governments of some countries give their citizens individual I.D. numbers. However, many countries
> (including New Zealand) do not. It is Okay to leave this section blank
> if your country does not have such I.D. numbers.

For India that number is the [Aadhaar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aadhaar). While it may not be fully recognized as the official number for some purposes, it's better to put it into the application, as it's the *de facto* national ID. Likewise SSN is not the official number of US citizens, but it's [recommended to use it](http://yij.ealc.illinois.edu/accepted/documents/Howtogetyourvisaandasampleform_000.pdf) for Japanese visa forms.

Comment: Although Japanese authorities will not really care if you write anything in there as they don't check national IDs, putting something legit in there can't hurt you at all.